# Vega Lite independent zooming between rows and columns

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have [this chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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) and as it currently stands, when you zoom in to one of the charts, it zooms in all the other ones too. Now, I don't mind this for the x axis where all the data has similar/related values. However for the y axis where the scales vary even within the same "series", zooming into one of the "variables" essentially hides the other "variables" of the same "series". So, I am looking for one of the following in order of my preference:

1. A way to have the y-axis zoom be independent between all the charts using Vega Lite.
2. A way to have the x- and y-axes zoom be independent between all the charts using Vega Lite.
3. A way to have #1 above but using Vega.
4. A way to have #2 above but using Vega.

Answer (score 0):

For concatenated charts, a way to do this is by applying custom bound selections to each chart, sharing selection names between chart for which you want shared zoom behavior. A simple example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVQAt54AHAZ2QHpKA3AUwHNYA6BgS3gIwCNm2B7Wo1gBaOIjJ14ZSuNiUAxrCxlmAKzL8AdpAC+AGnCEF2pfHwBtIxFAQ7UALbKA1vkgl+bLecP2IkOi0TaC8GfFs-fwAPcMh4AE8SOjcARwxYbw4ENnpIfSgAMzY6HGg3AAl+FToPAHc6LD1fSKh42ISk1PTMxHgc5PzIIpKy1EgAQQUFEobs7T1rOwNF-0kcOgU++dQIyMgAL35+BwB9GJ24xOSxr3gGmlg8Qe4vUagyJXWyPKhA4NDvqgLJAYgBdZYtKCHY4neIARnaVzct3ujx+kBeWjekA+jzo30Gf34IS0DEBYGBbXBKzAukWELsuzskCcWFcYw8tzyNICQWJoXCNOiiM6YzSGT6vX66OGpQqVUkdQaTSFrRF1yg4p62Vyg1l2IA6nQ2AwiCcvCccNxvnTIgz7DiZpsBDodqqDkdTuc0JdRVAUVgHk8oJjsbivuiiSSyZYQZBwc09tDTvD1cjvKjgxjXm5w-jI3zo+TKfHbX4yxAy6CQLogA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/cars.json"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Acceleration"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "zoom_x": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]},
        "zoom_y1": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["y"]}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Weight_in_lbs"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "zoom_x": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]},
        "zoom_y1": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["y"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the `zoom_x` selection is shared between the two charts, while each chart has its own version of `zoom_y`. The result is that x-axis zoom is shared between charts, and y-axis zoom is independent.

An analogous strategy works for your situation #2 (add a differently-named bound selection for each subchart).

For reproducing this in Vega, you might start by clicking the "Compiled Vega" tab within the Vega editor for the Vega-Lite charts: it will show you how these approaches are implemented in Vega.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how your example works. When I diff the 2 JSON objects in the `hconcat` array, they are basically the same except for the `encoding.y.field` value. If I had to modify your example to make both axes synchronized again, what would I have to change?